# OpenCL could not found Intel HD 4000

Tags: c++, opencl, gpgpu

I'll warn you in advance my written English it is not good, so please have some patience because I'll make a lot of errors.

I need to expose the graphic card in order to do some benchmarks with parallel algorithms on finite element analysis. I downloaded the intel SDK at this link https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-opencl.
I am using Ubuntu 16.10, so I followed all the instruction as explained in this post https://streamcomputing.eu/blog/2011-06-24/install-opencl-on-debianubuntu-orderly/.

When I run a simple algorithm which checks all the device, it only recognizes the CPU, failing to find the graphic card. The same program works well on a Mac (because OpenCL is in the stack of course).

```
// includes...

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
// See what standard OpenCL sees
std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;

// Get platform
cl::Platform::get(&platforms);

// Temp
std::string s;

// Where the GPU lies
cl::Device gpudevice;

// Found a GPU
bool gpufound = false;

std::cout << "**** OPENCL ****" << std::endl;

// See if we have a GPU
for (auto p : platforms)
{        
    std::vector<cl::Device> devices;

    p.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &devices);
    
    for (auto d : devices)
    {
        std::size_t i = 4;
        d.getInfo(CL_DEVICE_TYPE, &i);

        std::cout << "> Device type     " <<
                    (i & CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU ? "CPU" : "") <<
                    (i & CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU ? "GPU" : "") <<
                    (i & CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR ? "ACCELERATOR" : "");
        
        if (i & CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)
        {
            gpudevice = d;
            gpufound  = true;
        }
        
        std::cout << " Version  " << s << std::endl;

    }
}

if (!gpufound)
{
    std::cout << "NO GPU FOUND. ABORTING." << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
// Do other things...
```

the output is:

```
/home/andrea/Dropbox/fem/SiNDy/clfem/cmake-build-debug/vector_sycl
**** OPENCL ****
> Device type     CPU Version  
NO GPU FOUND. ABORTING.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried to add the current user in the video group, I also tried to install Intel Media Server Studio following the instructions coming with the package but I could not build the kernel because of some compile errors.

I also updated all the drivers with the automatic software update of Ubuntu, but still the GC is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try [beignet](https://01.org/beignet), which is an OpenCL implementation for IvyBridge+ iGPUs. There are packages of [beignet for Ubuntu 16.10](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/yakkety/+source/beignet). To be more precise, I think you are looking for the packages `beignet-dev` and `beignet-opencl-icd`. Test it yourself since I have no Ubuntu installation currently available. (However, beignet itself works pretty well on my Intel HD Graphics 520 and Antergos/Arch Linux)